# how to change focus of (this) from .box > .overlay (child)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
   <div class="box" id="box1">
    <div class="overlay" id="ovlay1">
    </div>
</div>
<style>
.box{
    height:200px; width:200px; 
}
.overlay{
    height:50px; width:200px; position:absolite; top:-50px;
}
</style>
<script>
$(".box").mouseover(function(){
    // $(".overlay").animate({
    // $(this).animate({    
        top: "+=50px",
    });
});
</script>
```

assuming i have about 5 of the .box divs, each with ascending id from box1 -> box5 etc.
the overlay should slide in on mouseover, but just on the hovered box.. i can't figure out the jquery function for this. runing animate on (".overlay") shows the overlay on every box, using (this) does not work because its obviously referring to (".box")...

how can i focus (this) on the overlay?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `find` method of jQuery:

```
$(".box").mouseover(function(){
     $(this).find(".overlay").animate({  
        top: "+=50px",
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Target the `.overlay` inside the currently hovered `.box`

```
$(".box").on('mouseover', function(){
    $(".overlay", this).animate({
        top: "+=50px",
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery will select the overlay that is the child of $(this):

```
$(this).children('.overlay').animate({
    top:"+=50px"
});
```

So the final piece looks like this:

```
$(".box").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).children('.overlay').animate({
        top:"+=50px"
    });
});
```